# Does adding a variable to a section provide staticness?

Tags: c, gcc, arm

Basically I'm asking if the declaration

```
unsigned char myBuffer[128] __attribute__((section (".some_section")));
```

is the same as

```
static unsigned char myBuffer[128] __attribute__((section (".some_section")));
```

I.e. I'm wondering if a variable is declared to be put in a specific section will provide the un-overridable feature as a `static` declaration does. Or is the memory of `myBuffer`, which is allocated in it's code-scope, available for others (outside of the scope) to overwrite? And when I later come back to `myBuffer`'s code scope it might not at all contain same values as before?

It's not all straightforward to test, since "undefined" behaviour more often than not (in simple code snippet tests) behave very defined.

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers and discussions.. Here comes a clarification of the intent.

In my case, in `buf.c` I have a struct `ms` with a `uint32_t`-array member (and other members but let's leave those out).

`buf.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>  // and many other includes

typedef struct myStruct {
    uint32_t a[BUFSIZE];
} MyStruct_t;

MyStruct_t ms  __attribute__ ((__section__(".do_not_init_section")));

void startUpCode() {
    // Init all members of struct to some values...
}

void foo(uint32_t* buf, int bufsize) {
    // figure out the right position in array to write to, i.e. find posInStruct. And memcpy...
    memcpy(&ms.a[posInStruct], buf, bufsize)
}
```

`main.c` is in a `while` loop and all other functions in `main.c` may call `foo(...)` in `bar.c`

I want of course `ms.a` to only be available for modification by `bar.c` during entire lifetime of program, which it is. (ok it's not protected against `extern` since not static, but that's fine, no other file is `extern`-ing `ms` in `bar.c`.) 
**BUT** the question I have is whether `ms` is really protected or not. Is the memory of `ms` dedicated for `ms` during entire lifetime or is that something that ONLY a `static` declaration will take care of??

I want all modification to be "remembered" throughout the program lifetime, e.g. I write some value to the array `ms.a[]` in the beginning and exit `foo(...)` in `bar.c`. Next time (after all other functions in program have done what they do), I make a new call to `foo(...)` in `bar.c` and I now want `ms.a[]` to be intact and contain same values as the last time I left it. It's not about other functions explicitly changing the values of `ms` or not, it's more about if they implicitly happen to write to the memory of `ms` when `ms` not in scope, since the memory is not dedicated when out of scope!?

If it had nothing to do with `global`s or `section`s, I would be confident by declaring the struct `static` and problem would not exist. But I'm a bit unsure with the `section`-ing part, if it really protects and holds the values of `ms` in memory intact.

OMG, I've never edited with so much text added, I hope someone can edit and make it more compact and clever.

Comment: Please, explain what does it mean **un-overridable feature** in your question. What feature are you talking about?

Comment: @LuisColorado I mean that with `static` the memory of the variable is allocated and reserved for that variable alone... no one else (even outside the scope of the variable) can accidentally overwrite that piece of memory

Comment: with or without static, except in fortran, that allows space to be shared (in commons) all variables are reserved a space alone (no sharing possible)  but if your problem is not to accidentally overwrite that variable, for example with a buffer overrun, you are not secure in that case.  Even belonging to a different section, memory protection does not apply here.  all writable sections are put together by the linker.  And so, why not ask what is actually worrying you instead of making assumptions about the `static` keyword?  This is an instance of the XY problem.

Comment: @LuisColorado I think you answered the "EDIT2" in the question. I don't know what u think is wrong with my assumption on static? Imagine the question didn't include the `section` and I would say that I want to remember the value of my variable between calls to the C file where the variable is scoped globally. You would have told me to declare the variable static, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `section` attribute is intended to be used [with an initialized definition of a global variable](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) only. I.e. having a static storage class in any case. And it will not add the restricted scope feature which the `static` keyword does. So no, it is not providing "staticness".

Comment: +1 for the link. How "global" are we talking about. In my case, the variable is initialized "global" within the entire file, but that's it. I mean, it's not declared within a function. Secondly, I don't get this at all "I.e. having a static storage class in any case".

Comment: Global variables in `C` terms are the ones which are defined outside of any function (including `main`). They are all having *static* storage class, i.e. have a lifetime of the entire program run. As opposed to the function local variables (without `static` qualifier) which have an automatic storage type, and exist only at a time the function is executing. You might want to research more about these.

Comment: I've edited with some clarification .. but anyway... I don't get a warning as the link says "GCC issues a warning and otherwise ignores the section attribute in uninitialized variable declarations"... I donnu

Comment: I mean, the way I understand it.. the variable in my example is global and have a lifespan of the entire program... but unlike the link example (and yours) it has nothing to do with main.

Comment: Yours is global, that's fine. But not initialized. Try explicitly enabling the `-Wignored-attributes` warning (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html). Also see in the `map` file where this variable is actually going.

Comment: Aha... now I saw it.. the `= { 0 }` at end of declaration in link example. So you're saying I should just do `MyStruct_t my_struct  __attribute__ ((__section__(".do_not_init_section"))) = {.a = 0,  .b=0}` .  And the use `static`.. BAM! We're home! Right?

Comment: This is what the docs say. But be careful, you are telling the compiler (and the reader of your code) that it should be initialized to `0`, but in fact no one is going to do that (unless you actually make the startup code to do that as you do for `.bss`). Adding `static` in this case will only restrict the scope of the variable to the given file. It won't change the way of how it is stored.

Comment: That is just to follow the doc and get past warnings. `foo()` contains the actual initialization of the member values. You always conclude with an enigma :). Are we good?

Comment: The enigma is about the scope? That's simple. Globals defined without `static` can be `extern`-ed in other source files. With`static` they cannot.

Comment: Lol it wasn't about the scope, but there I learnt something new. The enigma was about you having an opinion about what the code is actually telling the reader (which was a good point), to which I replied the useful values of members are set in the startup code, being `foo() `. So.. with all that, it's good?

Comment: Last edit... Kindly view and answer. I'll accept your answer regardless but it saves me and others some time for not posting a new question.

Answer (score 1):

`static` has two meanings, depending on the context used.  In a block, automatic scope, `static` means to make a variable global life, while maintaining the scope indicated by the block nesting.  When used on a global file scope, it means not to extend the scope outside of the file it is defined on.  Anyway, the attribute you specify has only sense on global variables, so in some sense those are `static`, meaning they have the global life attributes.  Global scope (against file or compilation unit scope) can be controlled by the compiler by making the variables globally accesible or not (this means the variable name goes to the symbol table for linking or not).  If you say something like:

```
int main()
{
    static int array[] __attribute__((__section__(".do_not_init_section")));
}
```

you probably won't have access to that variable from other modules (the compiler will not publish the variable name in the symbol table), as the compiler states local scope to `main` only.

Anyway, the `__attribute__` keyword is a gcc-only feature (however CLANG, I cannot assure, implements it also) so the best way to proceed is to make some tests, until you get (and are satisfied) with the response.

## EDIT

If you think that you can protect a variable from accidental overwrite by putting it in a different section, then you are wrong.  Protection is implemented at the process level, but any section that has read/write access can be overwritten, independently of where in the code you are accessing it.  The code normally belongs to a section, and the code it accesses is normally in different sections, so think on this and try to guess how can protection differentiate you are accessing your variable on purpose or by accident.

Comment: I think I understand.. Your saying that global variables have the same life attribute as non-global but `static`. And when you declare a global variable `static` you are not adding to the life attribute, but rather only limiting the variable to the scope. Right?

Comment: Nope, I'm saying that `static` gives eternal life to variables, but the life of a variable is completely independent (and so does the compiler) of the visibility (which is implemented by including or not the variable in the symbol table for the compiled object)  Being invisible in scope doesn't prevent you to accidentally write over it, even in the case the variable belongs to another section.  Memory protection is not implemented at the section level.

Comment: Ok great. So in order for me to both protect the variable (during entire program lifetime) AND put it in the section `.do_not_init` I have to use `static` on the global variable?

Comment: No, use `const`.  Then it will be put in the section `.rodata` that ends in the text segment... and so, it is now writable.  But you can only initialize it, you cannot modify its value.

Comment: I have to be able to modify during runtime... Alot of modification aswell

Comment: I think I should write a new question for this explaining everything...

Comment: then you have no alternative but be cautelous.  The machine cannot know if some variable access is allowed or not, at runtime... that requires far more checkings than efficiency of code mandate.

Comment: You can edit your question.   you can save variable contents in a file, and restore them when access is granted, but not at memory level... the memory your receive is for storing data... and storing data is donde by means of mem move... the machine does not know the meaning of the data your are moving, and also it doesn't know the high level semantics you used when programming.

Comment: It's a trace buffer which is put in that section so that a soft reset of the processor does not reinit the buffer.. That all works, but some suspicious behavior made me  question the staticness of the variable

Comment: By the way, have you heard about VALGRIND?  it's a tool that allows you to check a program against illegal kind of access.... this can be the solution to your problems.